# $wpdb update multiple checkboxes

Tags: wordpress

I tried to update multiple rows in wordpress that contains checkboxes ( if checked 1 else 0) but it does not work correctly. I have 3 rows:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| dept_id | dept_name | dept_status |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
|       1 | Services  |           1 |
|       2 | Products  |           0 |
|       3 | Users     |           0 |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

If I want to activate dept `users` by checking the checkbox status then it writes 1 for products, which is wrong. Another example: if we have all dept_status 0 and trying to update products, then it affects services. I can't figure it out..what is wrong in my code...
Here is my code:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['update'] ) ){
...
for ($i=1; $i<$deps_var; $i++) {
    $updatedeps=array(
        'dept_name' => $_POST['dept_name'][$i], 
        'dept_status' => isset($_POST['dept_status'][$i]) ? 1 : 0
    ) ;

    $where=array('dept_id' => $_POST['dept_id'][$i]);
    $wpdb->update( $departments, $updatedeps, $where);

    }
...
}
```

and the form:

```
<tr>
        <input name="dept_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_id'] ?>" class="small-text">
        <td><input name="dept_name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_name'] ?>" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="dept_status[]" value="<?php echo $dep['dept_status']; ?>" <?php echo ($dep['dept_status']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?>></td>
      </tr>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

PS: It works fine if I use "text" instead of "checkbox"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please remove value from the checkbox input field and try below one.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dept_status[]" <?php echo ($dep['dept_status']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?>>
```

Comment: $deps_var = count($_POST['dept_id']);

for ($i=1; $i<$deps_var; $i++) {
    $updatedeps=array(
        'dept_name' => $_POST['dept_name'][$i], 
        'dept_status' => isset($_POST['dept_status'][$i]) ? 1 : 0
    ) ;

    $where=array('dept_id' => $_POST['dept_id'][$i]);
    $wpdb->update( $departments, $updatedeps, $where);

    }

Comment: And also please check did you define global $wpdb;

Comment: I think so. I have 1 only in the first row, If I want to activate the third, then it goes to the second... I replaced checkbox with text and it works fine ( I simply put 1 or 0 and then update) But no with checkbox

Comment: In checkbox value, you can add "dept_id" and then use this one     $updatedeps=array(
        'dept_name' => $_POST['dept_name'][$i], 
        'dept_status' => in_array($_POST['dept_id'][$i], $_POST['dept_status']) ? '1' : '0'
    ) ;

Comment: I tried your suggestion... it works fine for all rows but not for first one

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: dept_status;     Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: Thanks man! It works! I put $i = 0.. now it's working! I couldn't update the first row! Thank you very much!